# Google direction route from current location (LocationServices.FusedLocationApi)

Tags: android, google-maps, direction

I am following these awesome instructions on how to draw directions from origin to destination it almost works as I want.
I have a strange problem.

When I want to set my longitude and latitude like follows I get a crash:

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
LatLng origin = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

But when I write numbers like (60.1,14.2) where I have the long and lat which is just a random location it works.

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

**LogaCat**

> 04-30 15:43:05.950 818-818/mawemo.stadsguiden E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main Process: mawemo.stadsguiden, PID: 818
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object
> reference at
> mawemo.stadsguiden.MainActivity.addMarkersRoute(MainActivity.java:324)
> at mawemo.stadsguiden.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:420)
> at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown
> Source) at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown
> Source) at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:395) at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.v$a$a.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:82)
> at maps.ei.bu$6.run(Unknown Source) at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

**UPDATE**

Why the minus? You just can't hand out minus without a reason

**UPDATE 2**

I have tested to declare two global variables like this

```
Double lat = 0.0;
Double lon = 0.0;
```

And then try to pass the values in with Location as follows:

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

lat = location.getLatitude();
lon = location.getLongitude();
```

So please dear Stack Overflow tell me what I am missing.

Comment: As the crash log said, getLastLocation() method returns null. It means, fused provider has no previously received location. The solution, request for location updates. You can check this link
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API

Comment: @Blackkara can you post comment as  answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getLastLocation() method retuns null. Because fused provider has no previously received location

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

So, then when you attempt to use like below, throwing exception.

```
LatLng origin = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

You need to make location request, [Check this link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API)